# using ontouch listener to get finger position

Tags: android, android-imageview, ontouchlistener

im trying to use the ontouch listener to get the position of the finger but nothing is being printed to the logcat. Whats wrong with my code?

```
              ImageView Im2;
 FrameLayout.LayoutParams layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Im2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    Im2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {    
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

               Log.d("  main ", " value of x  down" + event.getX());
            } 
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                  Log.d("  main ", " value of x  move " + event.getX());
            }
            return false;
        }
    });




}
```

Comment: add Log.d before the first if

Comment: @pskink nope it does not work.

Comment: does not make sense to me. Are you sure your logcat is working?

Comment: are you sure you touch that ImageView ?

Comment: yes i am touching it and my logcat works

Comment: its a mystery, maybe the parent steals the events ?

Comment: What is your log level set to? To view debug log level, your log level should at least be set to debug. This is the only problem that I can see

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your onTouch fonction always return **false**
so try this code instead of yours

```
 Im2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {    
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
           Log.d("  main ", " value of x  down" + event.getX());
           return true;
        } 
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
              Log.d("  main ", " value of x  move " + event.getX());
              return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```